# Scope of an CTE in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

```
WITH emp_CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS IdentityId, *
    FROM dbo.employee )
SELECT * FROM emp_CTE
```

This works fine

If the same query is written like this.

```
WITH emp_CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS IdentityId, *
    FROM dbo.employee )
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES    
SELECT * FROM emp_CTE
```

it gives a message telling `emp_CTE` does not exist.

Is there any way we can overcome this issue?

thanks
Prince

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The CTE is part of the subsequent statement only.

The subsequent statement can be a single SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, or a compound (with UNION, INTERSECT etc)

For example:

```
;WITH cte1 AS
(
   select ...
), cte2 AS
(
    select ...
)
SELECT ...
UNION 
SELECT ...;
```

The rule of thumb is that the scope is until where next `;` would be. A semi-colon  terminates any statement but is optional unfortunately.

Your failing code above is actually this

```
...;
WITH emp_CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS IdentityId, *
    FROM dbo.employee )
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES; 
SELECT * FROM emp_CTE;
```

So the CTE is only in scope up until `...EMPLOYEES;`

Comment: the miracle of Stack Overflow is that I can sit here at nearly 1030 pm local time, drinking a beer and wondering why my code isn't working and then within seconds find exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 12):

In short: NO. A CTE is valid exactly for the single, next statement - no more. And there's no way to "extend" the life of a CTE either.

From [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

> *A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of **a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement**. A CTE is
>   similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object **and
>   lasts only for the duration of the query**.*

You can:

- turn your CTE into a view and use that view for your queries - views are available as long as they are defined
- store the results of the CTE into a temporary table or table variable for further processing
- change your statements after the CTE so they can be executed as a single statement

  ```
  WITH emp_CTE AS (
  ......)
  SELECT (list of columns)
  FROM emp_CTE
  INNER JOIN dbo.Employees e ON ......
  ```