# CTE not Recognized

Tags: t-sql

why isn't my CTE accessible from my last selects?  I'm asking specifically how I have my CTEs listed, I'm missing something simple such as how I'm separating the last two

```
    with ParentsIdsWhoHaveInventoryWithManifests_CTE(brokerIds)
    as (...)
        ...)
        select someField from ParentsIdsWhoHaveInventoryWithManifests_CTE

    ;with SpecificBrokersTicketIds_CTE(ticketIds)
    as (...)
        select someFieldfrom ParentsIdsWhoHaveInventoryWithManifests_CTE

    ;with ProductionIdsWhichHaveManifests_CTE(productionIds)
    as (...)
        select productionIds from ProductionIdsWhichHaveManifests_CTE

    ;with InventoryRow_CTE(row)
    as (select row from Inventory where TicketId = @TicketId)

    ;with InvenotrySection_CTE(section)
    as (select section from Inventory where TicketId = @TicketId)


    select @ManifestId = ManifestId from Productions p where p.ProductionId = @ProductionId
    select @ProductionId as ProductionId_Used
    select @ManifestId as ManifestId_Used
    select @TicketId = TicketId from inventory where ProductionId = @ProductionId

...

update Venue_ManifestDetails
        set Row = row from InventoryRow_CTE,
        Section = section from InvenotrySection_CTE
        where TicketId = @TicketId
```

The problem is it doesn't recognize `InventoryRow_CTE` or `InvenotrySection_CTE` CTEs in my update statement.

Comment: you can have one 'with' (bur multiple cte clauses) and one 'select' per cte. That's the syntax!

Comment: CTEs are only available for the subsequent statement.  See this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840168/scope-of-an-cte-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: but I want my last 2 CTEs to break away from that pattern and be able to do this but you say that's not possible?

Comment: You'll need to use views or temporary tables -- ctes are just a temporary view available to a single statement following its declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CTE only in one subsequent statement. You cannot use it in 2 or more statements.

[MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) explains it this way:

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement.

If you want to store the results of your CTE, use a temporary table or view and put all the records from CTE into it..

Answer (score 0):

A CTE is just syntax
If you need to reuse it repeat it
I know it seems odd but that is how it is
It is just syntax - copy paste

You can use a #temp or a table variable