# Using CTE with same name several times in same query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've used the same `cte` several times in one script without issues, but I just wanted to double-check.

Let's say my script looks like this:

```
;with cte as
(
    select provider, count(*) as 'rows_count'
    from table1
) select *From cte

;with cte as
(
    select fname, count(*) as 'totals'
    from table_another
) select *From cte

;with cte as
(
    select sum(sales) as 'total_sales
    from table_yet_another
) select *From cte
```

Are there any issues to using the same `cte` with different `select` statements? Or should they have different *names*?

Comment: Its fine, see [Scope of an CTE in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840168/scope-of-an-cte-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: In theory it's possible to do so. However I would recommend to use different names to keep it code readable and not make mistakes (Always consider the fact that someone else might need to edit or troubleshoot the code somewhere in the feature).

Answer (score 2):

The name only needs to be unique within a single statement. So what you have is okay (if a bit confusing), but this would not be:

```
with cte as
(
    select provider, count(*) as 'rows_count'
    from table1
), cte as
(
    select fname, count(*) as 'totals'
    from table_another
) select *From cte
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not the same query.  A cte may only have one select statement.  So that is three distinct statements.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a CTE is local to the statement. You can repeat them between different statements (but not twice in the same one). Although I would recommend using meaningful names for each one, just like you would with a table.