# How to insert into more than one variables from a CTE in various conditions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, common-table-expression

There is one table that I used `with` clause for SQL queries.

As it's stated in the title, I want to insert into `@tempTableA` or `@tempTableB` from `SomeTable` in different conditions.

But it does not work. What did I misunderstand about CTE? Is there any other way to achieve?

```
declare @tempTableA table (FieldId nvarchar(4000), FieldName1 nvarchar(4000), FieldName2 nvarchar(4000), FieldName3 nvarchar(4000))

declare @tempTableB table (FieldId nvarchar(4000), FieldName1 nvarchar(4000), FieldName2 nvarchar(4000), FieldName3 nvarchar(4000))

; with SomeTable as (
    select
        FieldId
        , FieldName1
        , FieldName2
        , FieldName3
    from tableA
    cross apply tableB)

insert @tempTableA 
select * from SomeTable where FieldName1 > 10

insert @tempTableB
select * from SomeTable where FieldName1 <= 10
```

Comment: is there an error you receive? also, you missed a parenthesis after `cross apply tableB`

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scope of an CTE in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840168/scope-of-an-cte-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CTEs only with a single **query** after their definitions (scope of a CTE and subsequent CTEs are just for a single query), for example:

```
create table Table1 (
    pkTable1 int primary key
    , fkTable2 int
    , Column1 nvarchar(max)
)

create table Table2 (
    pkTable2 int primary key
    , fkTable3 int
    , Column2 nvarchar(max)
)

create table Table3 (
    pkTable3 int primary key
    , Column3 nvarchar(max)
)

; with cte1 as (
    select pkTable1, fkTable2, Column1
    from Table1
)
, cte2 as (
    select pkTable2, fkTable3, Column2
    from Table2
)
, cte3 as (
    select * from cte1
        join cte2 on cte1.fkTable2=cte2.pkTable2
)
select * from cte3
    join Table3 on cte3.fkTable3=Table3.pkTable3
```

<sup>(*: For this is just a demonstration, don't bother with how it can be optimized nor the query makes any sense. )</sup>

If you want to use it in multiple statements, go for **temporary table** or `table variable` or you need to define the `CTE` again for the next statement.

For example you can use temporary table like following to achieve same.

```
declare @tempTableA table (FieldId nvarchar(4000), FieldName1 nvarchar(4000), FieldName2 nvarchar(4000), FieldName3 nvarchar(4000))
declare @tempTableB table (FieldId nvarchar(4000), FieldName1 nvarchar(4000), FieldName2 nvarchar(4000), FieldName3 nvarchar(4000))
select
    FieldId
    , FieldName1
    , FieldName2
    , FieldName3
    into #t3 --Assign to temp table
from tableA
cross apply tableB

insert into @tempTableA 
select * from  #t3 where FieldName1 > 10

insert @tempTableB
select * from  #t3 where FieldName1 <= 10

drop table #t3 --Drop the table
```

For your scenario, you don't need `CTE`, you can write your query like the following:

```
declare @tempTableA table (FieldId nvarchar(4000), FieldName1 nvarchar(4000), FieldName2 nvarchar(4000), FieldName3 nvarchar(4000))
declare @tempTableB table (FieldId nvarchar(4000), FieldName1 nvarchar(4000), FieldName2 nvarchar(4000), FieldName3 nvarchar(4000))
insert into @tempTableA 
select
    FieldId
    , FieldName1
    , FieldName2
    , FieldName 
from tableA
cross apply tableB where FieldName1 > 10

insert @tempTableB
select
    FieldId
    , FieldName1
    , FieldName2
    , FieldName 
from tableA
cross apply tableB where FieldName1 <= 10
```

Comment: Seems a bit pointless having `#t3` - this might be more effective `insert into @tempTableA select FieldId, FieldName1, FieldName2, FieldName3 from tableA cross apply tableB; DELETE FROM  @tempTableA OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @tempTableB where FieldName1 <= 10`

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree with you, i just explained the issue with the CTE, i will update the answer for simplified version also. Thanks